# WebApi POST request gets handled by GET

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to consume my WebApi. Here is the relevant code:

```
var insertRequest = new RestRequest("MappedSystem", Method.POST);
insertRequest.AddBody(new MappedSystemCreateModel
                {
                    MappedSystemDetails = new MappedSystemCreateModel.Details
                    {
                        SystemName = "TestName",
                        SystemVersion = "TV"
                    }
                });
var response = RestClient.Execute(insertRequest);
```

But when I debug my WebApi it hits the Get() method:

```
public class MappedSystemController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMappedSystemService _mappedSystemService;

    public MappedSystemController(IMappedSystemService mappedSystemService)
    {
        _mappedSystemService = mappedSystemService;
    }

    public MappedSystemViewModel[] Get()
    {
=>      return _mappedSystemService.Get();
    }

    public MappedSystemViewModel Get(Guid id)
    {
        return _mappedSystemService.Get(id);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public MappedSystemViewModel Post([FromBody]MappedSystemCreateModel model)
    {
        return _mappedSystemService.Post(model);
    }
}
```

I think there must be something wrong with my routeConfig, but I don't know at this point:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{id2}/",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, id2 = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a Post route handler interceptor checking to see if I had correctly added a trailing '/'.  Since I hadn't it responded with a 301 and redirected.  Somehow/somewhere in the RedirectPermanently() the Verb was getting lost.  The answer was to originally make the request with the trailing '/'.  But of course this does shed light on the error found in the redirect.

Also, I needed this following code on the request or the body wouldn't deserialize:

```
insertRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
```